# Prove $4\sum_{cyc} \frac{a}{(a+b)^2}\le\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c$

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Hello I want to prove that $$4\sum_{cyc} \frac{a}{(a+b)^2}\le\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c$$
for all $a,b,c>0$. I try multiplying by all the denominators and expanding but I get over 30 terms. Is there a nice proof?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: $(a+b)^2 \ge 4ab$, so 
$$\frac{a}{(a+b)^2}\le\cdots$$

Comment: What a easy proof